# Should I flag this answer for suspicious activity or am I just crazy?

Tags: discussion, voting-fraud

I'm a long-time SO user, but generally don't dip into the nuanced world of moderation, so I'd love some guidance on what should be done.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14324459/1255748) has a surprisingly high number of upvotes, considering how bad it is. It doesn't answer the question, provides an absolutely insane solution (especially considering the elegance of other answers), and feels like the answerer and editor may have been collaborating in a devious sort of way. Is this a case where someone has been using multiple accounts to boost their score?

Frankly, I couldn't care less about someone else's account having more points or upvotes or whatever, but I *am* immensely curious if my hunch is right. Please help me satisfy my curiosity!

Is there anything actually suspicious about the linked answer or am I the crazy one here?

Comment: You have to realize that a lot of the people who come in from search engines with the problem likely *don't care* about the why - they just care about finding a solution that will do what they want the way they want it to be done.

Comment: 3 years old post with 30 votes... It is unlikely to be wrong to start with and really should not be investigated now unless you see recent flood of votes. Don't forget that votes indicate usefulness of answer to visitors (who may need just copy-paste ready solution of any quality)

Comment: @animuson agreed. It's sad though that this answer's "solution" has 30 upvotes when the actual is a one-liner and built into the standard library.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Maybe I'm just too picky about code quality. :) I agree that this is likely too subtle to be proper voting fraud. It's just troubled me for years (only slightly mind you) and a recent upvote on my answer resurfaced that curiosity. I figured I'd finally ask and see what everyone thought. Again, more curiosity than concern here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does not look like anything is wrong with that particular Q&A.

Your answer is correct (and was useful to OP), but generally useless for other visitors that are looking for practical solution to the problem. This comment gave the reason for vote difference long time ago:

> The accepted answer doesn't solve the original problem. Assuming that you are only given the string 'b.c', this is the only answer that solves the problem.

If I would land on that question and see code solution in accepted answer I'd say:"duh... I know I can nest calls... not what I'm looking for... look there is another one that seem to be useful. Bingo!".

Your options:

- be happy that you've provided information useful for at least some people and move on with your life.
- provide another practical solution in your answer. I don't know python, but I doubt one can easily write code that converts `"a.b"` string into `func(func(x, a),b)` at run-time (definitely not completely trivial in C++/C#/JavaScript). It looks like you even have such solution in comment to other answer (making that other answer even more valuable).

Comment: Got it, check! Sadly, other answers below that one DO have the elegant solution but get eclipsed by the highest voted one. Looks like if I want to save hapless Googlers' some code I should edit my old answer.